# The argument type 'MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am building a flutter app and I am trying to pass data to a page using MaterialPageRouter but I am getting an error that says **"The argument type 'MaterialPageRoute dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'"**. Does anyone know what is this cause and please can anyone assist.

Here's the code that is causing the error

```
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        ProductDetails(
                                            id: bottleCategory.bottleList[index].id,
                                            bottleName: bottleCategory.bottleList[index].bottleName,
                                            image: bottleCategory.bottleList[index].image,
                                            price: bottleCategory.bottleList[index].price)));
                          },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Navigator.push, not Navigator.pushNamed

Comment: I answered it 1 min earlier. :)

Answer (score 8):

You are passing a `MaterialPageRoute` hence you need to use `Navigator.push`, not the `Navigator.pushNamed`.

`Navigator.pushNamed` is for using named routes.